# \part title does not result centered

Tags: sectioning, positioning

The first `\part` title (`\part{introduction}`) does not result in the center of the page, but it ends at its top, with an horizontal line above. On the contrary, all the other `\part` titles are correctly centered.
If, for example, I put a chapter before the first `\part`, the problem does not occur anymore. What could the problem be?
Thank you

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany, abstracton]{toptesi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{topfront}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex,linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks, framed]{mcode} %framed, bw

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0}
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\graphicspath{{imm/}}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bindingoffset=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    

\linespread{1.2}
\selectfont
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\fontfamily{ptm} \selectfont
\include{./Frontespizio/frontespizio}
\selectlanguage{english}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\part{Introduction}

\chapter{Tissue Engineering}\label{introduction}
\input{Tissue}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in `toptesi`, in my opinion.

Just issue `\mainmatter` before the first `\part` command.